# Tuning the Model to Obtain Better Performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I made a model for regression problem which is to predict a value from 9 input variables.
Development of the model is ANN with library of Keras

In this model with compile and fit method, I already predicted the output value.
However, I got the bad evaluate score. I evaluated the model using RMSE and R2

RMSE between the (those have been normalized) predicted and labelled value is 0.207,
RMSE between the (original form) predicted and labelled valued is 215,
R2 is 0.4

How can I modify my model to obtain better result (low RMSE and high R2)?
or is this model acceptable?

```
import keras


model = keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(36, input_dim=9, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))

callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mean_squared_error', patience=10)

from keras.models import Model

model.compile(loss=[keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()],
             optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999),   
             metrics=[keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])

model_history = model.fit(myscaled_x_train.values, myscaled_y_train.values, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=1, validation_data=(myscaled_x_valid.values, myscaled_y_valid.values),
                         callbacks=[callback])

model_history
```

Looking for the solution and explanation, if somebody can help me with this.
Thankyou

Comment: What have you tried so far?

You have a number of options. Have you plotted the history of the loss and accuracy so you know what they look like?

Have you tried adding additional layers, changing the number of neurons, etc?

Have you tried optimizing your learning rate?

Comment: yes, I already plotted the history, already used 3 hidden layers with different numbers of neurons,  also changed the lr values several times.

Are there any other options? that's the best evaluate score that I got @SeanPayne

Answer (score 1):

There are different techniques to improve performance:

- you can add more hidden layers;
- you can change layers number of units, activation functions and other hyperparameters;
- you can try different type of neural network. Where are different types: ResNet, inception blocks, RNN, etc.
- also there is a change you preprocessed your data wrong. Neural networks like to word with scaled features.

Comment: The dataset I have, 206 data which are divided into 3 categories: training data set (124 Data), validating data set (41 Data), testing data set (41 Data).
I already normalized all the data and used those data to build the model.

For the activation function, I already used rely, selu, tanh for hidden layer and the output layer is linear activation function. But still, the best activation function in my case is relu.
I can not use another type of neural network because I try to prove by using ANN with my data to obtain the good result.

that's why I try to more modify my model @Yoskutik

Comment: Well, 124 samples to train is too small for deep neural networks. Maybe you should try other models: _LinearRegression_, _RandomForestRegressor_ or any other regressors. Take a look at `scikit-learn` package

Answer (score 0):

if you use Neural network for a regression problem make sure you have a large dataset so it's use is justified. with smaller dataset it is much better to use statistical machine learning.